# Data Explorer slightly overeager to ellipt column headers

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer

The Data Explorer's results table (not to be confused with the underlying SQL tables) has default column widths that it decides on and sticks to. I don't know how they're calculated, but I'd guess it's based on the length of the header, the length of the data within, and a preset maximum. Thing is, the length-of-header bit is possibly a little off. See the following row of headers:

> [image]
>
> ```
> Original: Revision Number|Revision ID|  Event Type  |  Date  |  User Link  |Comment
> Ellipted: Revision Numbe…|Revision I…|  Event Type  |  Date  |  User Link  |Commen…
> ```

The last character of some of the columns is being ellipted. Thing is, there's (AFAICT) more than enough space there to show them (presumably allocated based on their lengths). Hence the post title - the headers don't need to be ellipted, but the last character of each is being cut off anyway.

(If you want to repro, [the above screenshot was taken from here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/155370/post-history-viewer?PostId=217884).)

---

[Okay, this is just crazy:](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/180640/reviews-on-a-post?PostId=222743)

> [image]
>
> ```
> Original:   Review Link  |Review Type
> Ellipted:   Review Link  |Review Type…
> ```

Yes, I know there's already a pull request pending to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) it, but I thought that was such an ...*interesting* example that it had to be put here for historical reference.

Comment: +1, this one's been bugging me for a while.

Comment: +1. I think this always happens when the values are shorter than the header. (and I always tries to click the border hoping for auto-fit, when in fact it doesn't)

Comment: Solution: Stop using Firefox ;) But yeah, let me take a look...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, that whole bit of code is kind of a mess...but I went ahead [and made it messier](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/43), just for you.

Fixed pending a pull and redeploy (it should also now behave better when clicking the column headers to sort them, too).