# Results table in Query SO

Tags: discussion, design, data-explorer

When using SO trying to find the Top 200 users in Europe,

```
SELECT TOP 200
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) AS [#],
   Id AS [User Link],
   DisplayName,
   Reputation,
   WebsiteUrl,
   Location
FROM
   Users
WHERE
   Location like N'%Europe%'
```

I got the following results

[image: Results in Query SO]

and

[image: Results in Query SO]

Notice anything weird? Some numbers don't show up completely.

Initially i thought it was a bug. Then, after quite some time, noticed the columns could be adjusted.

What could we do, design wise, to show users they can adjust columns?

Comment: Similar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228314/282094 and related:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdata-explorer%5D+width+is%3Aquestion

Comment: When I notice this in resultsets on one of my queries I simply make the label (a lot) longer so slickgrid is accommodating for a wider column.

Comment: Sure, I also did that @rene. But to know that was possible wasn't intuitive for me, took quite some time...

Comment: In theory I could add a background to the CSS class `slick-resizable-handle` but that looks a bit weird because the resize handle div is a few pixels off. I'm not sure how that can be prevented.

Comment: Better take advantage of what the community has to offer -> https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/132154/117492

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [Alexey Kolchenko](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/132159/117492)

> **Some points to consider:**
>
> 1. **Use clear visual cues** for users: change cursor type and show the border between rows (as on the pictures)
> 2. **Increase the width of the handling area** to make it easier to resize ([Fitts's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law) in
>      action!)
> 3. **Set default columns width** according to their content, so as to minimize resizing operations